# PSExec to execute sql scripts in SQL server of Remote machine

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, remote-desktop, psexec, mstsc

How to create a batch file to connect to Remote desktop and launch Microsoft Sql server and run some scripts.
I tried creating a batch file to connect to  using

```
@ECHO OFF
mstsc /v:"SERVERNAME"
```

But i was not able to pass username and password 
Can anyone advise on this.

**EDIT**

```
 psexec \\remotemachine-u username -p password ipconfig
```

Above one connects me to the remote machine and prints its Ip details.

Now I am trying to execute SQL script which is in D:\ of remote machine to execute in Microsoft SQL server (connection) in the remote machine.
Is that possible.

Comment: If you run mstsc /? from the command line ... there doesn't seem to be an option to pass username and password through.

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with GUI.  If you want to execute something to run on a remote server then use PSEXEC.

Comment: @Squashman - Now i am using psexec to connect to remote machine. Is it possible to execute sql script in the Microsoft sql server in the remote machine

Comment: So change ipconfig to your SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSTSC to create the connection, with credentials (be sure to check the box that says "Allow me to Save Credentials"), then save that information to an `.RDP` file

After you should be able to launch:

```
mstsc "MyConnectionFile.rdp"
```

In the connection configuration, there is also a tab: "Programs / Start the following programs on connection", which should get your scripts going.

In general, the issue is to set up everything via the GUI, save it to an RDP file, and use that file in the future.